# Delphi try catch statement

Tags: delphi, try-catch

I want to do a try catch in Delphi.

I cannot put at the same time catch and finally statement.

But I want to catch exceptions with catch statement, and close connection in finally statement.

Delphi allows me to put only one of catch and finally.

How should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use nested try statements: try -> try -> except+end -> finally+end

Comment: Delphi does not have a "catch" at all. It is either "try..except..end" or "try..finally..end". As @JørnE.Angeltveit says, if you need both, you'll have to nest them.